# Notify when a post is published, with custom messages for Subscribers, Contributors + Authors

Tags: php, wordpress

This would seem useful for many WordPress sites, but I cannot find a full code.

We have a working codesnippet to notify Contributors when their post is published. But as we have User Submitted posts at the front end too, I want a different message to notify Subscribers when their post is published.

Most code I can find is based on the current user, but that responds to who is publishing the post, not who wrote it.

So this is our attempt - with 3 messages. But so far it always sends the final message. Can someone spot the error(s)?

Major thank you.

```
function notifyauthor($post_id) {

$post = get_post($post_id);
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";
        
//Gets all the data of the author
$authorData = get_userdata( $author );

//checks if the post author has the role of Author or above
    if (in_array( 'author', 'postseditor', 'editor', 'administrator', $authorData->roles)) {

//message for authors in Author role and above
$message = "
Dear ".$author->display_name.",

Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.

View your post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."

the rest of my message 1"
;   }

    elseif (in_array( 'contributor', $authorData->roles)) {

//message for authors in Contributor role       
$message = "
Dear ".$author->display_name.",

Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.

View your post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."

the rest of my message 2"
;   }

    else {

//message for authors in Subscriber role
$message = "
Dear ".$author->display_name.",

Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.

View your post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."

the rest of my message 3"
;  }

   wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message);
} 
add_action('publish_post', 'notifyauthor');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your comparison function isn't right.

Based on your additional comments, this would send the specified email to the users with specific roles.

```
function notifyauthor( $post_id ) {

    $post    = get_post( $post_id );
    $author  = get_userdata( $post->post_author );
    $subject = 'Post Published: ' . $post->post_title . '';

    if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $author->roles, true ) ) {
        // message for authors in Author role and above.
        $message = '
        Dear ' . $author->display_name . ',
        Your post, "' . $post->post_title . '" has just been published.
        View your post: ' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '
        the rest of my message 1';
    } elseif ( in_array( 'contributor', (array) $author->roles, true ) ) {

        // message for authors in Contributor role.
        $message = '
        Dear ' . $author->display_name . ',
        Your post, "' . $post->post_title . '" has just been published.
        View your post: ' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '
        the rest of my message 2';
    } else {
        // message for authors in Subscriber role.
        $message = '
        Dear ' . $author->display_name . ',
        Your post, "' . $post->post_title . '" has just been published.
        View your post: ' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '
        the rest of my message 3';
    }

    wp_mail( $author->user_email, $subject, $message );
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'notifyauthor' );
```

Comment: Howard, major thank you for responding. array_intersect is new to me.  But am I comparing two arrays? - maybe that's misleading on my part. I just want to message according to the role of the post author.  So it seems like one array, but tell me if I'm wrong!

Comment: It seems like you're comparing two arrays. The roles that are allowed and the current user roles (as an array). Is this not the case? Your usage of `in_array` is definitely incorrect.

Comment: If the Administrator or an Editor publishes a post written by a Contributor, as is often the case, then I want the emailed message to be designed for the Contributor.  In other words, it doesn't matter about the current user role, the message should be selected according to the role of the post author.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I've updated based on your comments.

Comment: Awesome! Just tested it as Admin, publishing posts by Subscribers, Contributors and myself, and get the custom message each time.  Thank you.